# Android Studio 3.5 Gradle Location for macOS?

Tags: macos, cordova, android-studio, ionic4

I am using Apache Cordova by way of Ionic 4 framework, and recently updated my Android Studio to Android Studio 3.5. When I go to run `ionic cordova build android`, I now get the error:

```
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

With the previous version of Android Studio, I could specify the location of Gradle in my `.bash_profile` config, but I have no idea where the new Gradle directory is in Android Stduio 3.5. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Android Studio gradle location has been changed in Android Studio 3.5. I also used .bash_profile to add the path to gradle installed with Android Studio and after the upgrade to 3.5 the path is invalid. To fix I just installed local gradle by running

```
brew install gradle
```

then run gradle -v to make sure that it is available and this should fix the problem.

Please note that Android Studio will automatically use the Gradle wrapper and pull the correct version of Gradle rather than use a locally installed version. If you wish to make Android Studio to use a locally installed version of Gradle, you can change the version used by studio. Beneath your Android Studio's project tree, open the file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change this entry to smth like below:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message after updating Android Studio to 3.5 on Windows 10.

Solved the Issue by manually installing gradle and adding it to the environment path.

Answer (score 0):

I spent too many hours trying to get it to work on AS 3.5 but couldn't get gradle to work. In the end I rolled back to 3.4.2, everything's working again.

I disabled auto updates now :)